# How to enable logcat output on Huawei MediaPad M3

Tags: android, adb, logcat, huawei-mobile-services

The MediaPad M3 does not log anything related to the app I am developing (compared to other Android devices). I understand that the log level usually can be set on Huawei devices via a hidden menu.

I came across these instructions many times while searching for the solution: https://gist.github.com/Shallong11/8403487

However, this is a tabled and it doesn't have GSM support and a Dialer / Phone application. So I fail at step one: dial *#*#2846579#*#*.

Update #1: I've tried everything listed here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59259/typing-dialer-secret-codes-in-devices-other-than-phones
Nothing works. The only reaction I've gotten: startActivity call with Intent.ACTION_DIAL is handled by Contacts app. Quite strange that there's a Contacts app but no Dialer...

It's probably meaningful to add that debug logs are displayed but stack traces of app crashes are not.

Update #2: I've also tried with some of these secret codes; nothing works: http://mobilespecs.net/phone/codes/Huawei/Huawei_MediaPad_M2.html

Comment: This may be of use: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59259/typing-dialer-secret-codes-in-devices-other-than-phones

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately none of this works for my case. Check my question update for details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because there is no dialer on the tablet, open calculator in landscape mode and enter 
"()()2846579()()=" and the hidden menu should appear.

[Here's a video demonstration.](https://youtu.be/LwgiHFUMkKQ)

Also please note that you'd need to restart the device afterwards in order for the changes to be applied.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe this question got an answer 4 months after being posted. I also can't believe it's an answer that actually works. Thanks a lot! Hope you don't mind my edit.